# Binary file offline sort failure

Tags: c++, sorting, binary

I am supposed to write a program that writes randomly generated numbers into a binary file, then output them. After that, I have to sort the numbers from smallest to largest and display them to the screen. Everything works fine to the best of my knowledge until the data is displayed supposedly after the sort. The data is not sorted when displayed and I couldn't figure out way.

This is my code followed by the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h> 


using namespace std;


//Function prototypes
void Write_File(int num);
void Sort(int num);
void Read_File(int num);


/******************************************************************************
* Assignment: Offline Sorting
*
* Overview:
*   This program is supposed to generate random numbers display them then 
*   save them to a binary file. Then reads the valuse sort them then dispaly 
*   the sorted data
*
* Input:
*   The user inputs how many random numbers should be generated
*
* Output:
*   
*   
*********************************************************************************/
int main()
{
    int num = 0;

    cout << "Enter a positive number to generate random numbers ";
    cin >> num;

    Write_File(num);
    Sort(num);
    Read_File(num);


    return 0;
}

 //Functions Definitions
/********************************************************************************
* Purpose:
*       This function write's the randomly generated numbers to a binary file
*
*********************************************************************************/
void Write_File(int num)
{
    ofstream fout("sortfile.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::beg);
    int random = 0;

    //checks if file is opened
    if (fout.is_open())
    {
        //writes data to the file
        for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
        {

            random = rand();
            fout.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&random), sizeof(int));
            cout << random << endl;
        }

        fout.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, File not opened" << endl;
    }
}

/********************************************************************************
* Purpose:
*       This function read's the form the binary file
*
*********************************************************************************/
void Read_File(int num)
{
    ifstream fin("sortfile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::beg);
    int number = 0;

    cout << endl << "randomly generated numbers after sorting\n";

    //checks if file is opened
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        //reads data from the binary file
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            fin.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&number), sizeof(int));
            cout << number << endl;
        }


            fin.close();
        }
        else
            cout << "File not opened in read phase." << endl;
}

/********************************************************************************
* Purpose:
*       This function compare's and sort's the numbers in the binary file
*
*********************************************************************************/
void Sort(int num)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    fstream file_io("sortfile.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary | ios::beg);

    if(file_io.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num - i -1 ; j++)
            {
                file_io.seekg(sizeof(num1) * j);
                file_io.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num1), sizeof(num1));
                file_io.seekg(sizeof(num2) * j - 1);
                file_io.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num2), sizeof(num2));

                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    temp = num1;
                    num1 = num2;
                    num2 = temp;
                }

                file_io.seekp(sizeof(num1) * j);
                file_io.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num1), sizeof(num1));
                file_io.seekp(sizeof(num2) * j - 1);
                file_io.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num2), sizeof(num2));
            }
        }
        file_io.close();

    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Enter a positive number to generate random numbers 4
> 41
> 18467
> 6334
> 26500
>
> randomly generated numbers after sorting
> 41
> 18467
> 6334
> 26500
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Sort` function, you're seeking on byte boundaries, rather than on `int` boundaries (4 bytes usually). Instead of

```
file_io.seekg(sizeof(num2) * j - 1)
```

do

```
file_io.seekg(sizeof(num2) * (j + 1) );
```

(You could have done `* (j-1)` but you swap if the first is smaller than the second, so you need num2 to be the next number, not the previous.).

I optimized out writing to the file if there are no changes, but other than fixing that index, there's no change:

```
void Sort(int num)
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    fstream file_io("sortfile.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary | ios::beg);

    if(file_io.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num - i -1 ; j++)
            {
                file_io.seekg(sizeof(num1) * j);
                file_io.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num1), sizeof(num1));
                file_io.seekg(sizeof(num2) * (j + 1 ));
                file_io.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num2), sizeof(num2));

                if (num1 > num2)
                {
                    file_io.seekp(sizeof(num1) * j);
                    file_io.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num2), sizeof(num2));
                    file_io.seekp(sizeof(num2) * (j + 1));
                    file_io.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&num1), sizeof(num1));
                }
            }
        }
        file_io.close();

    }
}
```

Notes:

- I had to compile with `-fpermissive` due to odd warnings
- Reading and writing files like that is extremely slow.